# Root Sony Xperia Z1

Tags: root-access, sony-xperia

Is possible to do root Sony Xperia Z1 (c9603) with 4.4.2 version?

I searched on google, but all the tutorials are for other versions. I don't want to do a downgrade, so, is possible root without downgrade?

Thanks